# Matlab feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, matlab

I am trying to learn relevant features in a `300*299` training matrix by taking a random row from it as my test data and applying `sequentialfs` on it. I have used the following code:

```
>> Md1=fitcdiscr(xtrain,ytrain);
>> func = @(xtrain, ytrain, xtest, ytest) sum(ytest ~= predict(Md1,xtest));
>> learnt = sequentialfs(func,xtrain,ytrain)
```

`xtrain` and `ytrain` are `299*299` and `299*1` respectively. Predict will give me the predicted label for `xtest`(which is some random row from original xtrain).

However, when I run my code, I get the following error:

```
Error using crossval>evalFun (line 480)
The function '@(xtrain,ytrain,xtest,ytest)sum(ytest~=predict(Md1,xtest))' generated the following error:
X must have 299 columns.

Error in crossval>getFuncVal (line 497)
funResult = evalFun(funorStr,arg(:));

Error in crossval (line 343)
    funResult = getFuncVal(1, nData, cvp, data, funorStr, []);

Error in sequentialfs>callfun (line 485)
    funResult = crossval(fun,x,other_data{:},...

Error in sequentialfs (line 353)
                crit(k) = callfun(fun,x,other_data,cv,mcreps,ParOptions);

Error in new (line 13)
    learnt = sequentialfs(func,xtrain,ytrain)
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> func = @(xtrain, ytrain, xtest, ytest) sum(ytest ~= predict(Md1,xtest));

The function "func" is called by sequentialfs, which does not pass "Md1" to the "predict" function. Therefore, Md1 is unknown to that "cost" function. You should include "Md1=fitcdiscr(xtrain,ytrain);" within your "func" function.

Beside, "sequentialfs" does a 10-fold CV. Why are you trying to pass only 299 samples instead of all 300?

Comment: I am using 299 examples to train and 1 random example as xtest. Also, how should I modify my "func" function?

Comment: Call `Md1=fitcdiscr(xtrain,ytrain);` inside your "func" function. Save "func" in a seperate file if necessary. Remember, "sequentialfs" will pass 4 arguments `(XTRAIN,ytrain,XTEST,ytest)` to `func`. MATLAB is doing a 10-fold CV if you haven't disabled it already. Why would you need that single observation as a test set?

Comment: out of the 300 observations, I am taking one of them at random as my test data. Basically trying to implement cross-validation. Is it not the right way to do it?

Comment: MATLAB is doing that cross-validation already. You don't need to do it yourself. Just ,make sure you did NOT set `'cv' = 'none'` somewhere in your code.

Comment: ok, got it. So my function handle shuld look like this, right: `f = @(xtrain, ytrain, xtest, ytest) sum(ytest ~= predict(fitdiscr(xtrain,ytain),xtest)));` ?

Comment: Yes. You may need to save `fitdiscr(xtrain,ytain)` in a variable. I'm not sure if `predict` will accept a direct call. Just give it a go and see what happens. If it fails, save `func` in a seperate file in your working directory.

Comment: Okay, I will try both of them and then tell you what happens. Any ideas on how much time the code will take to run? I am using Matlab 2016.

Comment: Just wondering if that worked?

Comment: No it didnt. Both methods didnt work. Same error :( Some modifications and I get covariance matrix is not positive definite.

Comment: That basically brings it down to your data. Try adding noise (just some random numbers drawn from a distribution, may be Gaussian) with small magnitude. It is (probably) not an issue with the code. You can also check if you have any constant or almost constant features in your data. If yes, they would produce zero/near zero standard deviation. Remove them, if any.